# Enable and Disable ToolStripMenu entries in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, foreach, toolstripmenu

I have a `Form` that contains a `Menu` with two entries, which are *Menu* and *Tools*. The two Menues have some `SubMenus`.

Now i have a `TextBox` called `txtSelect` and a `Button` called `btnVisible`, if I enter 1,2 in the `TextBox`, the `SubMenu`s in the `Menu` should not be visible. I written the following code, bit it is Hard-written.

```
ToolStripMenuItem[] mstrip = new ToolStripMenuItem[] { msO1, msO2, msO3, msP1, msP2, msP3 };
if (txtSelect.Text.Length > 2)
{
    string word = txtSelect.Text;
    string[] splt = word.Split(',');
    for (int x = 0; x < mstrip.Length; x++)
        mstrip[x].Visible = true;
    for (int x = 0; x < splt.Length; x++)
    {
        int y = Convert.ToInt32(splt[x].ToString()) - 1;
        if (y >= 0 && y < mstrip.Length)
            mstrip[y].Visible = false;
        textBox1.AppendText(mstrip[y].Text);
        textBox2.AppendText(mstrip[y].OwnerItem.Text);
    }
}
```

I want to use `foreach` loop instead in a `Button` Click Event and have attempted with the following, however the result is not the same as with the code above.

```
foreach (ToolStripMenuItem mnItem in msMenus.Items)
{
    MessageBox.Show(mnItem.Text);
    for (int i = 0; i < mnItem.DropDown.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(mnItem.DropDown.Items[i].Text);
        mnItem.DropDown.Items[i].Visible = true;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Could you please clarify the question? What do you need it to do?

Comment: i want that above validation with foreach loop....i don't want hardcode...,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, may be you want something like :

```
List<Int32> lstindex = new List<Int32>();
String[] splt = txtSelect.Text.Split(',');

// initialize list of indexed for textbox
foreach (String str in splt)
{
    lstindex.Add(Convert.ToInt32(str) - 1);
}

// for each menu
foreach (ToolStripMenuItem mnItem in msMenus.Items)
{
     // for each menu item
    foreach (ToolStripItem item in mnItem.DropDown.Items)
    {
        // if index of item is in the list of indexed, set visible to false, otherwise to true
        item.Visible = lstindex.Contains(mnItem.DropDown.Items.IndexOf(item)) ? false : true;
    }
}
```

Comment: i want the subItems of all Menus should be in sequence...., Like 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10............,